# How to bind image width to scroll for certain height?

Tags: jquery, css

I am just trying to attach image to scroll so that when user scroll down image size/width will reduce *smoothly* with scroll for certain height or vice verse.

Smoothness like this [link](http://callmenick.com/tutorial-demos/resize-header-on-scroll/)

I just want reduce size of image from 0px to 700px with smooth animation.

I used ***waypoints, bind function, addclass- remove class, transition (css)*** and much more but no success.

My code for waypoints

Jquery code

```
$('#slide-1-base').waypoint(               // create a waypoint
    function(direction) {
        if (direction === 'down') {
            $('.logo img').stop().animate({ "width" : "80%"}, 1000);
        }
        else {
            $('.logo img').stop().animate({ "width" : "100%"}, 500);
        }
    });
```

HTML code

```
 <div class="logo">
     <a href="#slide-1">
         <img src="assets/icon/logo.png"/>
     </a>
</div>
<section id="slide-1" ></section>
```

Comment: Do you have an example of what you need? I really don't understand what you are asking. Do you want the image to resize proportionate to the scroll height? Like <img width= "orig_size/scroll_height">? And does the image always stays on top? Is it a fixed position image?

Comment: @Alexey Yes, Image(logo) will always stay on top and it is fixed position. your logic for width is correct "orig_size/scroll_height". But it should be smooth and for big scroll.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from from you comment reply, this is what you need -

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
  var scrollAmount = $(document).scrollTop(); // This returns how far away you are from top of your page.
  var picWidth = 100; //Insert any value here for your picture size
  //$('.logo img').css('width', picWidth - (scrollAmount/100));
  $('.logo img').animate({width:(picWidth - (scrollAmount/100))}, 100);
});
```

This is a rough representation. You need to tchange the logic and the math of the function, but this will resize your image based on how close you are to the top of your page.

Comment: Exact answer for my question. But It is not smooth as i want. Smothness should be like animation() function.

Comment: @thanks it works. but not to smooth  `$('.logo img').animate({width:(picWidth - (scrollAmount/40))}, 8);`

Answer (score 1):

```
If you want to reduce the size then there is scroll function. check this
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LLbAu/

Comment: Thanks anusha for answering my question. But i don't want that because it is **not smooth** and it **cant be use for big height** (700px for my case). http://jsfiddle.net/LLbAu/51/

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need something like this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLbAu/55/). 
I think (based on what I see from your comments and previous answers) you want to check the height of the window the user is using and depending on what that returns you want to reduce the width of your specific element..

```
$( window ).scroll(function() {
     if($(window).innerHeight() > 700){
       $('.box').animate({'width': '50'}); 
     }else{
         $('.box').animate({'width': '100'}); 
     }

});
```

Comment: Definitely works! Just scroll! It just checks the height of the window on scroll. When it is more than 700 it animates! Just be patient after scrolling and be sure to have a window height of more than 700px

Comment: Yeah it is working but it is not bind to scroll and work suddenly. I just want reduce size of image from 0 to 700 with smooth animation.